# Algebraic numbers that cannot be expressed using integers and elementary functions

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, radicals, elementary-functions

> Can we give an *explicit${^*}$* example of a real algebraic number that provably cannot be represented as an expression built from integers and elementary${^{**}}$ functions only?

---

${^*}$ *explicit* means we can write down a polynomial equation with integer coefficients having the algebraic number as a root, and an interval with rational bounds that isolates that root.

${^{**}}$ *an expression built from integers and elementary function only* means any *valid* expression in the *set of elementary expressions $\mathcal{E}$* (as defined in [that question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/145299/9550) at MO). Briefly, it is any finite combination of the following:

- the imaginary unit $i$,
- the exponent $x\mapsto e^x$,
- the [principal branch](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipalBranch.html) of the [natural logarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalLogarithm.html) $x\mapsto\ln x$, provided $x\ne0$, and
- the multiplication function $(x,y)\mapsto x\cdot y$.

Note that it allows to express constants $\pi$, $e$, integers, rationals, sums, powers, radicals, and also trigonometric and hyperbolic functions and their inverses, e.g. 
$$\pi=i\cdot i\cdot i\cdot \ln(i\cdot i).$$

---

*Update:* I [reposted](https://mathoverflow.net/q/178831/9550) this question at MO.

Comment: If the field of numbers that can be expressed in terms of integers and elementary functions is algebraically closed, then the answer is no

Comment: Well, that is to say, for some subset of elementary functions and their compositions. I.e. things like $\cos ((p/q) \arctan (a/b))$ like what you wrote. If any such set is algebraically closed then the answer is no.

Comment: My understanding is that the background to Hilbert's 13th Problem was a result that the general sixth degree polynomial's roots cannot be expressed in terms of functions of one argument.  I'll try to find a reference, but I take it your "elementary functions" are of one argument.

Comment: @hardmath: I think you mean the general 7th deg.

Comment: @hardmath The solution to Hilbert's $13^{th}$ Problem found by Kolmogorov and Arnold states that 2-argument functions are sufficient to solve algebraic equations of $7^{th}$ degree. For example, addition, multiplication and raising an expression to a power are all 2-argument functions.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to be more explicit about what you mean by 'elementary functions' - in particular, whether you just mean the exp-based functions (cos, sin, arctan, log, etc.) or whether you mean to explicitly allow e.g. things like hypergeometrics.  Also, the Kolmogorov/Arnold result is _not_, AFAIK, speaking specifically in terms of elementary functions and so may not be (entirely) germane here.

Comment: Incidentally, am I the only one to find the choice of tags misleading? I think it would be much more appropriate to have (elementary-functions) before (precalculus) and (trigonometry), because this is not some matter of pedagogy, but rather a deep question. The point is to attract the right people to it! If it were me, I might also add (transcendental-number-theory) and (model-theory), because those fields are germane.

Answer (score 10):

This may not be what your are looking for but, after some tinkering, I found your example in fact *can* be expressed in radicals. Let,

$$x = 2\cos \frac{2\arctan k}{5}$$

then $x$ is a root of,

$$x^5-5x^3+5x+2\left(\frac{k^2-1}{k^2+1}\right) = 0$$

This is the [*DeMoivre quintic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Examples_of_solvable_quintics) in disguise,

$$x^5+5ax^3+5a^2x+b=0$$

and is solvable in radicals. Your $\alpha$ then has the radical expression,

$$\alpha = 2\cos \frac{2\arctan 2}{5} =\left(\frac{-3-4i}{5}\right)^{1/5}+\left(\frac{-3+4i}{5}\right)^{1/5} = 1.807059\dots$$

Comment: Thanks! I fixed my question. I hope the new example should work. Welcome to try to prove me wrong this time as well :)

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov: Actually, it is as well. :) All $2\cos\frac{2\arctan k}{n}$ can be expressed in radicals. The new one is just $$2\cos \frac{2\arctan 2}{7} =\left(\frac{-3-4i}{5}\right)^{1/7}+\left(\frac{-3+4i}{5}\right)^{1/7} = 1.900768\dots$$

Comment: Oops... I need to think deeper to find a real example.

Answer (score 9):

If I'm not mistaken, this is a profound problem and little is known about it. Some years back there was an article in the American Mathematical Monthly by Timothy Chow, *What is a Closed-Form Number?* (pdf [here](http://math.mit.edu/~tchow/closedform.pdf)). I believe what Chow calls *EL numbers* are the same as the numbers you have identified.

This area is closely connected with [Schanuel's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture). Chow proves one conditional result that is relevant here:

- If Schanuel's conjecture is true, then the algebraic numbers $\alpha$ belonging to the class EL are precisely those whose equations are solvable over $\mathbb{Q}$ (meaning the Galois group of the splitting field of the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ is solvable).

See corollary 1 on page 444 of Chow's paper. I'm not sure a single explicit example that answers your question is known, although I'd be absolutely delighted to be shown otherwise.

Comment: That PDF is interesting but I only have a vague understanding of the terminology. Are the terms "transcendence degree", "fields over $\mathbb{Q}$", and "irreducible polynomial" topics that would be covered in undergrad algebra?

Comment: Definitely the terms "fields over $\mathbb{Q}$" and "irreducible polynomial" would be covered in a standard undergraduate algebra course that covers the elements of Galois theory. "Transcendence degree" might be a different story, but the concept itself is not unduly difficult: it is the maximal number of algebraically independent elements in a field extension, very analogous to how the dimension of a vector space is the maximal number of linearly independent elements. All of this would certainly be covered in a respectable graduate algebra book like Lang's.

Comment: user43208 is right. The elementary numbers (see Wikipedia) can be generated by applying elementary functions to the rational numbers. Chow's numbers EL are the explicit elementary numbers.

Comment: see also my answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828551/polynomials-with-degree-5-solvable-in-elementary-functions/4225322#4225322