# Is there a formula which gives the solutions of a general fifth grade equation by using trascendental functions?

Tags: galois-theory, radicals

Thanks to Galois we know that the solutions of a general fifth order equations cannot be expressed by means of radicals.

Can we exclude that a formula exists if we are allowed to also use (any composition of) trascendental functions like: $\exp$, $\log$, $\tan$, $\arctan$?

Comment: [possibly relevant MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32099/what-is-lagrange-inversion-good-for/32261#32261)

Comment: [Two](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526100) related [questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582825). See also [Bring radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical).

Comment: Also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function) and [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuinticEquation.html)...